Latch inference using assign statement in Verilog
Intel/Altera Quartus Prime flags latch inference for the output resource in the following code:
wire       ff_out;
reg  [2:0] count;

assign ff_out = (count < 3) ? 1'b1 : (count == 7) ? 1'b0 : ff_out;

always @ (posedge clk) begin 
    if (!rstn) begin 
        count <= 0;
    end else begin 
        count <= count + 1;
    end 
end 


Should this kind of coding style be avoided?
What are the pitfalls that can happen due to this kind of latch inference?


The original question showed this code:
wire       output;
assign output = (count > 3) ? 1'b1 : (count == 7) ? 1'b0 : count;

There are a few issues with the Verilog code.
There is a syntax error because output is a Verilog keyword, and it can not be used as a signal name.  Your simulation and synthesis software should generate a compile error.
Another issue is that the (count == 7) condition will never be reached because it is already covered in the higher priority (count > 3) condition.  You declared count as a 3-bit signal, which means it can have the following values: 0-7.  If count is 7, then (count > 3) is true.
Another strange thing is when count is 0-3, in which case output is assigned the value of count:
output = count

There is a signal width mismatch; the LHS is 1-bit wide, but the RHS is 3-bit wide.  This means you really have:
output = count[0]

This is legal, but often tools will generate a warning message.
I don't understand why your tool flags output as an inferred latch, but maybe the above factor into it.  The output signal is intended to be combinational logic.  For synthesis tools to infer latches, it usually means you have failed to make assignments to the signal in all cases.  However, it seems you have made assignments in all cases.  Regardless, the coding style should be improved as mentioned above.

The code in the question was changed after I wrote the answer above.  Here is the new code in the question:
wire       ff_out;
assign ff_out = (count < 3) ? 1'b1 : (count == 7) ? 1'b0 : ff_out;

Since ff_out is on both sides of the continuous assignment, this describes a combinational feedback loop.  In this case, I am not surprised that your tool warns about an inferred latch.  This coding style should be avoided.  You need to think more carefully about what logic gates you are trying to model with the Verilog code; I recommend drawing a simple logic schematic diagram for yourself to visualize the circuit you need.

I have corrected the code for the mistakes pointed out in the answer. Could you please revisit?

@lousycoder: After you corrected the Verilog code, did you re-run with your tools to see if you now get a better result?

This is a (reproduced version of the) code that I have come across at work.

@lousycoder: The edit to your question invalidated my original answer.  In the future, it would be better to keep the question as-is once you have received an answer, then post a separate, new question.  Regardless, I have updated the answer.

I'd keep this in mind. Can I roll back the edits so that the previous version is visible and then post a new question?

do that in the future

@lousycoder: No need in this case.  Since the answer answered both questions, go ahead and Accept.

What are the possible timing hazards with this coding style?
